# In MVC 5 Razor, how do you pass a different model to the controller than is being returned?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, models

I have a cshtml page with 3 charts. In order to generate the data for the charts I have 3 different methods, but they all take the same parameters. So I created the following model.

```
public class ChartParameterModel
{
    [Required]
    public String BankID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public Boolean PercentByItemCount { get; set; }
}
```

The controller for my page has the following action:

```
public ActionResult GetCharts(ChartParameterModel model)
{
    return View(ChartDataController.GetChartData(model.BankID, model.CompanyID, model.StartDate, model.EndDate, model.PercentByItemCount));            
}
```

In the cshtml page it seems you can only have 1 model. So I'm not sure how to go about passing the ChartParameter model say on a button click and then get back my chart data.

If I hard code the ChartParameterModel it works fine. Just need to get values from the cshtml to the action.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SeriesDataItem>>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard Home";
}

<div class="chart-wrapper">
            @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model.First())
                .Name("chtItemsByType")
                .Title(title => title
                    .Text("Items By Type")
                    .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Top)
                )
                .Legend(legend => legend
                    .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Left)
                )
                .Series(series =>
                {
                    series.Pie(
                        model => model.ItemCount,
                        model => model.ItemType,
                        null,
                        model => model.Exploded
                        )
                        .Labels(labels => labels
                            .Visible(true)
                            .Template("#= dataItem.ItemCount#")
                        )
                        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                            .Visible(true)
                            .Template("#= dataItem.ItemAmountDisplay# #= dataItem.YValue# %")
                        );                        
                })
                .Theme("Bootstrap")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100%;" })           
            )
        </div>
```

Comment: Difficult to understand what your problems is. If you have a view based on your model, then the properties of the model will be sent to the controller. Show your view.

Comment: Maybe I have to include the parameters as part of the series data? Or somewhere in that model?

Comment: Prior to your edit, how do you think that anyone would have know you were using `Kendo.Chart`? If you need `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SeriesDataItem>>` and `ChartParameterModel` in the view, then use a view model that contains 2 properties, one for each of the models

Comment: Thanks I was thinking that. I didn't think the chart was that important because my question was the more general "How can you pass a different model than you are using in the view", regardless of what control I am using.

Comment: @Cef there is absolutely no requirements on what model action accepts as arguments and what model it returns... It mainly depends on what you render in the view or run in JavaScript to invoke actions.

Comment: So in my case how would you pass the ChartParameterModel to the action (in javascript for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Cef,
yes, view model can be different depending on requirement. i.e. you can define model of type 'dynamic'.

So, there can be more than one action methods targeting to same view but different model.

Also, if you have model with all properties same for all actions, but differs for some properties, then you can include additional properties of type 'dynamic' that will accept data decided at runtime.

Also,in case all actions require all properties same but only some additional values vary, then you can keep view model same but varying properties can be passed as ViewBag values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("GetCharts", "Dashboard")',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         data: {
                 BankID: "48",
                 CompanyID: "0",
                 StartDate: "1/1/2001",
                 EndDate: "2/2/2002",
                 PercentByItemCount: false                            
               },
        });
```

And then it shouldn't matter what model is referenced by the view.